# Elasticsearch nested data search performance

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following problem:
I am storing books in an elastic database. **It is important that every word is stored as a separate entry** because it contains certain metadata that I need. Books belong to categories, book can belong to 1 or more categories, and it is changeable property (book - category relations are also saved in MySQL). Expected number of books is couple of thousands. I need to have fast search across all books by a word (e.g. someone searches for a word 'test', I would need to get books that contain that word, and in which pages.). It would also be possible to limit search by a category.

My dilemma is, should I save words for a book in a nested fields, e.g.

```
{
 "book_name": "book1",
 "book_categories": ["cat1", "cat2", ...],
 "book_words": [
   {
     "some_word_meta": "...",
     "page": 1
     "word_value": "word1"
   },
   {
     "some_word_meta": "...",
     "page": 1
     "word_value": "word2"
   } ... lots of these
 ]
},
{
 "book_name": "book2",
 "book_categories": ["cat5", "cat6"],
 "book_words": [
    {
    "some_word_meta": "...",
    "page": 1,
    "word_value": "wordx"
    }, ... lots of these
  ] 
}
```

In the above example, if I move a book from 1 category to another, I just need to update 1 record in elastic. **Would this nesting affect search performance?**

I could also not save categories info in elastic and always pass book names in a query (because MySQL knows which books are in a category), but then I would have something like this in a search query:
`book_name in ["book1", "book2", ... thousands more] and word == 'wordx'`. In this case, books could be flattened:

```
{
"book_name": "book1",
"page": 1,
"word_value": "word1",
"some_word_meta: "..."
},
{
"book_name": "book1",
"page": 1,
"word_value": "word2",
"some_word_meta: "..."
}
```

There is a lot of data repetition, every word knows to which book it belongs explicitly, and search query seems terrible.

I am pretty new to elasticsearch, and I still don't have the data set to try it, which of these solutions seems more likely to work, or is there some other solution that I didn't think of?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be having multiple indices and doing few operations on application side.

Indices: Books and Words

```
Books 
{
  "name" :
  "other_attributes"
}

Words
[
  {
    "metadata": ...
    "word": word1,
    "categories": ["thriller"],
    "book": ["book1_page1", "book1_page2"]
  },
  {
    "metadata": ...,
    "word": word1,
    "categories": ["romance"],
    "book": ["book9_page31"]
  }
]
```

When you say bring all the books with the words "Concepts",

```
GET words/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "word": {
        "value": "Concepts"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For category search,

```
GET words/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "categories": {
        "value": "Thriller"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To get all book with page number and metdata which has the word "*concept*" and belongs to "*romance*" genre,

```
GET words/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "FIELD": {
              "value": "concept"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "category": {
              "value": "romance"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note: You can also query on multiple indices.

Comment: Interesting idea, but the same word has different metadata in each book/page. Also I never need to search for categories, categories should just be a filter, e.g. `find word 'concepts' in books that belong to 'Thriller', 'Horror' etc categories.` This should return a list of words with its metadata, book, and page in that book.

Comment: This design will work for those use cases. To get it in single query, you can move the categories to words index. I have updated the answer with updated query